# I like to know if there is approximated expression of something

Tags: taylor-expansion

I like to know if there is approximated expression of below things.

$$e^{-x}\sum^{9}_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}x^{k}$$

$x$ is not always small.

I know behind part is Maclaurin series but summation range is specified.

How can i approach?

Thank you

Comment: The right hand side is "almost" $e^x$, so this expression should be close to $1 = e^{-x}e^{x}$..

Comment: No that is not true. Because x is not always small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{9}\frac{x^k}{k!} = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^9}{9!}e^{-t}\,dt=1-\int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{t^9}{9!}e^{-t}dt=1-\frac{x^{10}}{9!}\int_{1}^{+\infty}t^{9}e^{-xt}\,dt.$$

Comment: Is there closed form of integral in last equation?

Comment: @Kim: it is an incomplete $\Gamma$ function, hence the existence of a closed form depends on your concept of *closed form*.

Comment: Doing a partial integration I get $$\int_0^x{t^9\over9!}e^{-t}\>dt=-{t^9\over 9!}e^{-t}\biggr|_0^x+\int_0^x{t^8 \over 8!}e^{-t}\>dt\ ,$$ giving a first term $-{x^9\over 9!}e^{-x}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don`t know what is concept of closed form. Could you give me some topic or keyword about that? Thank you!

Comment: I fully agree with @Jack d'Aurizio: it is a "full-fledged" function (incomplete $\Gamma$), up to a const more precisely $\dfrac{\Gamma(10,x)}{10!}$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html Kim : The debate "is it a closed form or not" is not to be held: in mathematics, as long as you give a symbol or a name to something that was deprived of it, you have defined a closed form ! Nevertheless, many questions on this site, by students, are "is there a closed form for such and such"... though we know that in mathematics, this notion is usually of rather low magnitude.